# Is it possible to use single table for multiple connections in cassandra

Tags: cassandra-2.1, spring-data-cassandra, cassandra-cli

Is it possible to use single table for multiple connections in cassandra?

I am using a spring data for java connection and am trying to use python flask  for raspberry connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use single tale for multiple connections. I'm using Cassandra 2.2 where I connect using Java Astyanax driver and python pycassa client.

Are you referring about table lock for transactions? Cassandra does not use any locking mechanism on data, the below docs link describes more on transactions and consistency in Cassandra:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_transactions_c.html

Mention what you tried and problems you faced.